# Human readable SSL/TLS packets

Tags: encryption, ssl, wireshark, tls, tcpdump

If I have a protocol-analyzer/packet-sniffer, such as `wireshark` installed on a particular device..

(or in this case; `tcpdump` & `tshark` etc. on my smartphone..)

..should I be able to read that devices incoming & outgoing ssl/tls traffic, in an unencrypted/decrypted state?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will see the packets but the content will be encrypted.